# .htaccess to force HTTPS on all the site, and to force HTTP on one specific folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

I have a website where WordPress is installed in the root folder. I need to force HTTPS for WordPress. At the same time, I have a folder where another cms is installed where I want to force HTTP.

How can I achieve this?

Additional clarifications:

- `example.com` opens WordPress and I want to force HTTPS
- `example.com/xyz` opens another software and I want to force HTTP

Answer (score 0):

You can create sub directory site by adding following details to your .httaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xyz/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /xyzy/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If you want to force HTTPS please add below line

```
     # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /xyz/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /xyzy/index.php [L]
   # Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Make sure you have changed the directory path server name. If you want to load site without https then please remove https and add your server path.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Actually  the WordPress has links to the other software. So, when I force https in WordPress site and use the link in the same site to go to the application in subfolder, it also loads as https. Some design elements in this second software doesn't load on https. So I want http forced for this specific folder while https to be forced for original root site